# JQuery - Getting an attribute value from a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, attr

I'm trying to get the href attribute from a div with the class name 'download'.  I know I could use the following to access it from the DOM:

I know you can use `$(".download").attr("href");`

However, the html doesn't exist in the DOM yet, its only in a variable.

Is there a way to get from href from a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
$('<div class="download"><a href="example.com/image.png">Download</a></div>').find('a').attr('href')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ufz37/1

Comment: Thanks for this, Samich.  The href in my code is on an achor.  When I try the following I just get 'undefined'. alert($('<div class="download"><a href="http://www.example.com/image.png">Download</a></div>').attr('href'));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following code (or something similar):

```
var $a = $(document.createElement('a'))
  .addClass('download')
  .attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

Then you can get the `href` attribute from the `$a` variable with:

```
var href = $a.attr('href');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, KARASZI István.  I'm not sure it will work for me a I don't have the href/url string on its own.  The string I'm working with is html containing divs, classes, anchors etc.  I need to extract the href from the entire string.